# How to extract the elements from list of dictionary of dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

- I have a dictionary below which is coming from elastic search
- I need to extract some of elements and added to list

```
    searchtest = [{'_index': 'courses',
      '_type': 'classroom',
      '_id': '6',
      '_score': 1.0,
      '_source': {'name': 'Cost Accounting 400',
       'room': 'E7',
       'professor': {'name': 'Bill Cage',
        'department': 'accounting',
        'facutly_type': 'full-time',
        'email': 'cageb@onuni.com'},
       'students_enrolled': 31,
       'course_publish_date': '2014-12-31',
       'course_description': 'Cst Act 400 is an advanced course from the business school taken by final year accounting majors that covers the subject of business incurred costs and how to record them in financial statements'}},
     {'_index': 'courses',
      '_type': 'classroom',
      '_id': '7',
      '_score': 1.0,
      '_source': {'name': 'Computer Internals 250',
       'room': 'C8',
       'professor': {'name': 'Gregg Payne',
        'department': 'engineering',
        'facutly_type': 'part-time',
        'email': 'payneg@onuni.com'},
       'students_enrolled': 33,
       'course_publish_date': '2012-08-20',
       'course_description': 'cpt Int 250 gives students an integrated and rigorous picture of applied computer science, as it comes to play in the construction of a simple yet powerful computer system. '}},
     {'_index': 'courses',
      '_type': 'classroom',
      '_id': '8',
      '_score': 1.0,
      '_source': {'name': 'Accounting Info Systems 350',
       'room': 'E3',
       'professor': {'name': 'Bill Cage',
        'department': 'accounting',
        'facutly_type': 'full-time',
        'email': 'cageb@onuni.com'},
       'students_enrolled': 19,
       'course_publish_date': '2014-05-15',
       'course_description': 'Act Sys 350 is an advanced course providing students a practical understanding of an accounting system in database technology. Students will use MS Access to build a transaction ledger system'}},
     {'_index': 'courses',
      '_type': 'classroom',
      '_id': '9',
      '_score': 1.0,
      '_source': {'name': 'Tax Accounting 200',
       'room': 'E7',
       'professor': {'name': 'Thomas Baszo',
        'department': 'finance',
        'facutly_type': 'part-time',
        'email': 'baszot@onuni.com'},
       'students_enrolled': 17,
       'course_publish_date': '2016-06-15',
       'course_description': 'Tax Act 200 is an intermediate course covering various aspects of tax law'}},
     {'_index': 'courses',
      '_type': 'classroom',
      '_id': '10',
      '_score': 1.0,
      '_source': {'name': 'Capital Markets 350',
       'room': 'E3',
       'professor': {'name': 'Thomas Baszo',
        'department': 'finance',
        'facutly_type': 'part-time',
        'email': 'baszot@onuni.com'},
       'students_enrolled': 13,
       'course_publish_date': '2016-01-11',
       'course_description': 'This is an advanced course teaching crucial topics related to raising capital and bonds, shares and other long-term equity and debt financial instrucments'}},
     {'_index': 'courses',
      '_type': 'classroom',
      '_id': '5',
      '_score': 1.0,
      '_source': {'name': 'Theatre 410',
       'room': 'T18',
       'professor': {'name': 'Sebastian Hern',
        'department': 'art',
        'facutly_type': 'part-time',
        'email': ''},
       'students_enrolled': 47,
       'course_publish_date': '2013-01-27',
       'course_description': 'Tht 410 is an advanced elective course disecting the various plays written by shakespere during the 16th century'}},
     {'_index': 'courses',
      '_type': 'classroom',
      '_id': '1',
      '_score': 1.0,
      '_source': {'name': 'Accounting 101',
       'room': 'E3',
       'professor': {'name': 'Thomas Baszo',
        'department': 'finance',
        'facutly_type': 'part-time',
        'email': 'baszot@onuni.com'},
       'students_enrolled': 27,
       'course_publish_date': '2015-01-19',
       'course_description': 'Act 101 is a course from the business school on the introduction to accounting that teaches students how to read and compose basic financial statements'}},
     {'_index': 'courses',
      '_type': 'classroom',
      '_id': '2',
      '_score': 1.0,
      '_source': {'name': 'Marketing 101',
       'room': 'E4',
       'professor': {'name': 'William Smith',
        'department': 'finance',
        'facutly_type': 'part-time',
        'email': 'wills@onuni.com'},
       'students_enrolled': 18,
       'course_publish_date': '2015-06-21',
       'course_description': 'Mkt 101 is a course from the business school on the introduction to marketing that teaches students the fundamentals of market analysis, customer retention and online advertisements'}},
     {'_index': 'courses',
      '_type': 'classroom',
      '_id': '3',
      '_score': 1.0,
      '_source': {'name': 'Anthropology 230',
       'room': 'G11',
       'professor': {'name': 'Devin Cranford',
        'department': 'history',
        'facutly_type': 'full-time',
        'email': 'devinc@onuni.com'},
       'students_enrolled': 22,
       'course_publish_date': '2013-08-27',
       'course_description': 'Ant 230 is an intermediate course on human societies and cultures and their development. A focus on the Mayans civilization is rooted in this course'}},
     {'_index': 'courses',
      '_type': 'classroom',
      '_id': '4',
      '_score': 1.0,
      '_source': {'name': 'Computer Science 101',
       'room': 'C12',
       'professor': {'name': 'Gregg Payne',
        'department': 'engineering',
        'facutly_type': 'full-time',
        'email': 'payneg@onuni.com'},
       'students_enrolled': 33,
       'course_publish_date': '2013-08-27',
       'course_description': 'CS 101 is a first year computer science introduction teaching fundamental data structures and alogirthms using python. '}}]
```

Code is below

```
import json
import pprint


def details(searchtest):
    response = []
    for each in searchtest:
        course = {
            'name': each['_source']['name'],
            'proffesor':[]}
        
        for prof in each.get('professor', []):
            course['proffesor'].append(prof['_source']['name'])
            course['proffesor'].append(prof['_source']['department'])
        response.append(course)
    return response

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import pprint
    pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(4)
    pp.pprint(details(searchtest['hits']['hits']))
```

My output

```
[   {'name': 'Cost Accounting 400', 'proffesor': []},
    {'name': 'Computer Internals 250', 'proffesor': []},
    {'name': 'Accounting Info Systems 350', 'proffesor': []},
    {'name': 'Tax Accounting 200', 'proffesor': []},
    {'name': 'Capital Markets 350', 'proffesor': []},
    {'name': 'Theatre 410', 'proffesor': []},
    {'name': 'Accounting 101', 'proffesor': []},
    {'name': 'Marketing 101', 'proffesor': []},
    {'name': 'Anthropology 230', 'proffesor': []},
    {'name': 'Computer Science 101', 'proffesor': []}]
```

- My output proffesor list is coming as empty. The list has to filled with proffesor.name and proffesor.department

Expected output will contain list of professor name and department.

Error line in the code is below

`for prof in each.get('professor', []):`

Comment: your professor is in `each["_source"]["proffesor"]` and not `each["proffesor"]`

Comment: @JannesCarpentier I tried that also

Comment: Well yes you need to change the `for prof in each.get("professor"` line

Comment: @JannesCarpentier I understood the error sir in my code. i have tested with for prof in each.get(["_source"]["proffesor"],[])  . Can you help in writing the exact syntax

Comment: To check for None I'd just use `if each.get("_source", {}).get("professor") is not None`

Comment: @JannesCarpentier Thanks. but Still same output, not working

Comment: If you already accepted an answer how come it's still not working? If the answer doesn't work for you then why did you accept it?

Comment: @JannesCarpentier its working fine with the below code. but it would be great as i need to put .get method since my code is big need to check so many conditions so i wrote .get method. For the particular problem accepted answer works

Comment: Does my answer help?

Comment: @JannesCarpentier yes it helps but just one, i dont want to add in dictionary i just want in list as my output shown

Comment: I edited my answer to add it as a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `None` checks for every item in the response. This could be done more efficiently since the `_source` item is checked 3 times and the `professor` item 2 times.

```py
def details(searchtest):
    response = []
    for each in searchtest:
        course = {
            "name": each.get("_source", {}).get("name", ""),
            "professor": [
                each.get("_source", {}).get("professor", {}).get("name", ""),
                each.get("_source", {}).get("professor", {}).get("department", "")
            ]
        }
        response.append(course)
    return response

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import pprint
    pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(4)
    pp.pprint(details(searchtest))
```

```
[   {'name': 'Cost Accounting 400', 'professor': ['Bill Cage', 'accounting']},
    {   'name': 'Computer Internals 250',
        'professor': ['Gregg Payne', 'engineering']},
    {   'name': 'Accounting Info Systems 350',
        'professor': ['Bill Cage', 'accounting']},
    {'name': 'Tax Accounting 200', 'professor': ['Thomas Baszo', 'finance']},
    {'name': 'Capital Markets 350', 'professor': ['Thomas Baszo', 'finance']},
    {'name': 'Theatre 410', 'professor': ['Sebastian Hern', 'art']},
    {'name': 'Accounting 101', 'professor': ['Thomas Baszo', 'finance']},
    {'name': 'Marketing 101', 'professor': ['William Smith', 'finance']},
    {'name': 'Anthropology 230', 'professor': ['Devin Cranford', 'history']},
    {   'name': 'Computer Science 101',
        'professor': ['Gregg Payne', 'engineering']}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [53]: response
Out[53]: []

In [54]: for search in searchtest:
    ...:     response.append({'name':search["_source"]['name'],'professor':search["_source"]["professor"]})
    ...:

In [55]: response
Out[55]:
[{'name': 'Cost Accounting 400',
  'professor': {'name': 'Bill Cage',
   'department': 'accounting',
   'facutly_type': 'full-time',
   'email': 'cageb@onuni.com'}},
 {'name': 'Computer Internals 250',
  'professor': {'name': 'Gregg Payne',
   'department': 'engineering',
   'facutly_type': 'part-time',
   'email': 'payneg@onuni.com'}},
 {'name': 'Accounting Info Systems 350',
  'professor': {'name': 'Bill Cage',
   'department': 'accounting',
   'facutly_type': 'full-time',
   'email': 'cageb@onuni.com'}},
 {'name': 'Tax Accounting 200',
  'professor': {'name': 'Thomas Baszo',
   'department': 'finance',
   'facutly_type': 'part-time',
   'email': 'baszot@onuni.com'}},
 {'name': 'Capital Markets 350',
  'professor': {'name': 'Thomas Baszo',
   'department': 'finance',
   'facutly_type': 'part-time',
   'email': 'baszot@onuni.com'}},
 {'name': 'Theatre 410',
  'professor': {'name': 'Sebastian Hern',
   'department': 'art',
   'facutly_type': 'part-time',
   'email': ''}},
 {'name': 'Accounting 101',
  'professor': {'name': 'Thomas Baszo',
   'department': 'finance',
   'facutly_type': 'part-time',
   'email': 'baszot@onuni.com'}},
 {'name': 'Marketing 101',
  'professor': {'name': 'William Smith',
   'department': 'finance',
   'facutly_type': 'part-time',
   'email': 'wills@onuni.com'}},
 {'name': 'Anthropology 230',
  'professor': {'name': 'Devin Cranford',
   'department': 'history',
   'facutly_type': 'full-time',
   'email': 'devinc@onuni.com'}},
 {'name': 'Computer Science 101',
  'professor': {'name': 'Gregg Payne',
   'department': 'engineering',
   'facutly_type': 'full-time',
   'email': 'payneg@onuni.com'}}]
```

OR

As you want list

```
In [57]: response = []

In [58]: for search in searchtest:
    ...:     response.append({'name':search["_source"]['name'],'professor':[search["_source"]["professor"]["name"],search["_source"]["professor"]["department"]]})
    ...:

In [59]: response
Out[59]:
[{'name': 'Cost Accounting 400', 'professor': ['Bill Cage', 'accounting']},
 {'name': 'Computer Internals 250',
  'professor': ['Gregg Payne', 'engineering']},
 {'name': 'Accounting Info Systems 350',
  'professor': ['Bill Cage', 'accounting']},
 {'name': 'Tax Accounting 200', 'professor': ['Thomas Baszo', 'finance']},
 {'name': 'Capital Markets 350', 'professor': ['Thomas Baszo', 'finance']},
 {'name': 'Theatre 410', 'professor': ['Sebastian Hern', 'art']},
 {'name': 'Accounting 101', 'professor': ['Thomas Baszo', 'finance']},
 {'name': 'Marketing 101', 'professor': ['William Smith', 'finance']},
 {'name': 'Anthropology 230', 'professor': ['Devin Cranford', 'history']},
 {'name': 'Computer Science 101', 'professor': ['Gregg Payne', 'engineering']}]
```

Using your code:
You don't have to loop through the `professor`. It's a dictionary, you can directly access by using keys

```
In [64]: import json
    ...: import pprint
    ...: def details(searchtest):
    ...:     response = []
    ...:     for each in searchtest:
    ...:         course = {
    ...:             'name': each['_source']['name'],
    ...:             'proffesor':[]}
    ...:         prof = each['_source']['professor']
    ...:         course['proffesor'].append(prof['name'])
    ...:         course['proffesor'].append(prof['department'])
    ...:         response.append(course)
    ...:     return response
    ...:
    ...:

In [65]: details(searchtest)
Out[65]:
[{'name': 'Cost Accounting 400', 'proffesor': ['Bill Cage', 'accounting']},
 {'name': 'Computer Internals 250',
  'proffesor': ['Gregg Payne', 'engineering']},
 {'name': 'Accounting Info Systems 350',
  'proffesor': ['Bill Cage', 'accounting']},
 {'name': 'Tax Accounting 200', 'proffesor': ['Thomas Baszo', 'finance']},
 {'name': 'Capital Markets 350', 'proffesor': ['Thomas Baszo', 'finance']},
 {'name': 'Theatre 410', 'proffesor': ['Sebastian Hern', 'art']},
 {'name': 'Accounting 101', 'proffesor': ['Thomas Baszo', 'finance']},
 {'name': 'Marketing 101', 'proffesor': ['William Smith', 'finance']},
 {'name': 'Anthropology 230', 'proffesor': ['Devin Cranford', 'history']},
 {'name': 'Computer Science 101', 'proffesor': ['Gregg Payne', 'engineering']}]
```

Comment: I understood your code fully. Just want to know how to updated my code `for prof in each.get('professor', []):`  to something like for prof in each.get(["_source"]["proffesor"],[])  as my it throws error

Comment: When you loop through dictionary, you get the keys of the dictionary using which you have to select the value. I don't recommend it unless necessary

Comment: its a big nested dictionary, i need to write so many condition like if id of professor match another match. So i wrote `.get` method. Can you help in writing the exact syntax for the code at `for prof in each.get('professor', []):`